# Find the next term: 1/5, 2/8, 2/12, etc

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Find the next term in the following sequence:

> $1/5$, $~~2/8$, $~~2/12$, $~~4/18$, $~~2/24$,  $~~?$

It's my first question so it might come off as a bit too easy.

Comment: Probably would have made it harder by reducing the fractions as much as you could.

Comment: @Spencerkatty Reducing in simplest form would have given multiple choices for each term .... it will also make it much tougher to go in the right direction ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given number sequence is derived from

> the sequence of prime numbers:
>
>  $~~~~$ $2$, $~3$, $~5$, $~7$, $~11$, $~13$, $~17$, $~19$, $~23$, $~\ldots$

The two entries of every pair are

> the difference and the sum of consecutive prime numbers

This yields

> 3-2/3+2, $~$5-3/5+3, $~$7-5/7+5, $~$11-7/11+7, $~$13-11/13+11, $~$17-13/17+13,

so that the next term will be $~$**4/30**.

Comment: You cracked it!!

Comment: What was  the inspiration behind the answer?

Comment: He may have searched the series of numerators on OEIS.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess..

> $\frac{2}{28}$

because

> Sum of numerator and denominator of a term equals difference between numerator and denominator of the next term.

This probably implies that

> The next term is of the type $\frac{a}{a+26}$

but I don't know why

> I'm guessing $a=2$.

A more complete answer will be required.

Comment: No. That is not the answer. Going by this  method can give numerous answer.

Comment: The actual logic gives one clear answer.

Comment: He was right on the 26 bit, his reasoning is connected with how the numbers are calced. He just lacked the top number. By this I mean his answer is 'incomplete' rather then 'based on a wrong method'.